# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/api/GetById/2'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

So many people have asked the same question but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

in postman when i call the 'http://localhost/api/GetById/2' i get the following error

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI http://localhost/api/GetById/2.

It works fine when I pass value 2 as a query string http://localhost/api/GetById/?id=2. Following is my WebApiConfig route parameter settings:-

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Following is my my API controller action method

```
    [Route("~/api/GetById/")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetUsers(id)), "application/json");

        return response;
    }
```

Will please someone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route to:

```
[Route("~/api/GetById/{id}")]
```

See this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

You can also be very specific to tell the code where the `id` value is coming from by using the `[FromRoute]` attribute like the following:

```
  public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromRoute]int id)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks @Jamie

Answer (score 0):

Replace `steve` with the controller name. You are mixing attribute routing and convention based routing. That is causing the routetable to barf. Since you use the route `~/api/getbyid/` it no longer has a controller reference from the convention based routing. So you need to do either all attribute routing or all convention based routing.

In addition you didnt take on the `int` at the end of your route, so .net router couldn't parse the query string and put your `integer` into your function call.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Steve")]
public class SteveController :ApiControlller
{
    [Route("GetById/{id:int}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetUsers(id)), "application/json");

        return response;
    }
}
```